# Event dependent change of precedence between conflicting default and user-defined bindings in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, bind, tk-toolkit

I have a Python GUI with Tkinter. In a class, I have some Text widgets. These have some [default bindings](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/entry.html#M65) some of which I'd like to replace preferably with `bind_class()`. I managed to do it with all, except the ones with a capitalized hotkey, like `Ctrl-E/A/B/F` (i.e. `Ctrl-Shift-e/a/b/f`). These I can only change by applying the `bind()` method on every widget separately. I am wondering why is this and if there is a smarter way to do this with `bind_class()`, which otherwise seems to have no effect on the above mentioned default bindings.

Please consider the code below. After clicking on each text widget and trying all four hotkeys (`Ctrl-b/B/y/Y`), one can see that all of them work in both widgets as expected, except for `Ctrl-B` (i.e. `Ctrl-Shift-b`), which works only if it is bound to the widget with `bind()`.

As I see this issue now: for a built-in function with a capitalized Key, the order of precedence is apparently the following: `bind()` > built-in function with a `return 'break'` at the end probably > `bind_class()`. This means, that `bind_class()` won't ever work and the built-in function only gets called, if there's no `return 'break'` at the end of the function referenced in `bind()`. At the same time, built-in hotkeys with lowercase keys (e.g. `Ctrl-a/e/b/f`) have somehow lower priority and even `bind_class()` can take precedence over them.

So my questions are:

1. Is my above conclusion correct, or there's something else to this?
2. Is this the intended functionality of `bind()` and `bind_class()`?
3. Is it somehow still possible to overwrite a built-in function like `Ctrl-B` using only `bind_class()` for all the widgets at once instead of `bind()`-ing them all one-by-one?

Any insightful comment is welcome. Thank you!

```
from tkinter import *

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Toplevel(root)
        self.window.lift()
        
        self.t1 = Text(self.window)
        self.t1.insert(1.0, 'Initial text in Text widget #1')
        #self.t1.bind('<Control-B>', self.func)
        self.t1.pack()
        
        self.t2 = Text(self.window)
        self.t2.insert(1.0, 'Initial text in Text widget #2')
        self.t2.bind('<Control-B>', self.func)
        self.t2.pack()
        
        self.t1.bind_class('Text', '<Control-b>', self.func)
        self.t1.bind_class('Text', '<Control-B>', self.func)   # This line has no effect.
        
        self.t1.bind_class('Text', '<Control-y>', self.func)
        self.t1.bind_class('Text', '<Control-Y>', self.func)
    
    def func(self, event):
        obj = root.focus_get()
        obj.insert(END, '\n'+str(event))
        return 'break'

root = Tk()
t1 = Test()
root.lower()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This was a very well-written question. Thank you for providing such a clear and concise example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of precedence doesn't change, it is the same for all widgets under all circumstances, and is always defined by the bindtags for the widget. So, to answer your first couple of questions: no, your conclusion isn't correct, and yes, this is working as designed.

The problem in this case is that at least on some platforms, `<Control-Shift-Key-B>` is associated with the virtual event `<<SelectPrevChar>>` (and `<Control-B>` is the same as `<Control-Shift-Key-B>`). When you press control+B, the event gets translated into the `<<SelectPrevChar>>` virtual event before being passed to the widget. The class binding is on that event rather than the raw keypress. In other words, the widget never sees `<Control-Shift-Key-B>`, it only sees `<<SelectPrevChar>>`.

You can solve this problem in one of two ways:

- you can remove the virtual event, in which case your class binding will work
- you can change the class binding for the virtual event

To remove that specific raw event from the virtual event and add an explicit binding to the raw event sequence you can do this:

```
self.window.event_delete("<<SelectPrevChar>>", "<Control-Shift-Key-B>")
self.t1.bind_class("Text", "<Control-Shift-Key-B>", self.func)
```

To change the class binding for the virtual event you can use `bind_class` on the virtual event:

```
self.t1.bind_class("Text", "<<SelectPrevChar>>", self.func)
```

To see a list of all virtual events and the keys they are bound to you can run this little bit of code which uses the `event_info` command with no arguments to get a list of virtual events, and then uses the same method to get information about each event.

```
for event in self.window.event_info():
    info = self.window.event_info(event)
    print(f"{event:<20s} => {', '.join(info)}")
```

Comment: This was extremely useful, thank you! I can see now a lot better what is actually happening. However, I am still left with a problem. If I `self.window.event_delete("<<SelectPrevChar>>")` (or just redirect it to something else as in the second option), then not only `Ctrl-B` gets freed up, but I won't be able to select the previous character with `Shift-Left` either. So what I'd rather like to do, is to break this association between `<Control-Shift-Key-B>` and the virtual event `<<SelectPrevChar>>`, but keep this virtual event together with its other associations. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: @Babber: I've updated my answer. In short, you can delete just the specific event from the virtual event instead of deleting them all.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I cannot try this right now, but it looks promising! Just one more thing, to get it right: so on my platform, `<Control-Shift-Key-B>` is translated to this virtual event. But its lowercase version `<Control-Key-B>` is not translated to some other virtual event (`<<PrevChar>>` I guess)? So I'm still not sure why the effects of these two shortcuts differ qualitatively. Why only one of them can be overwritten with `bind_class()` (without dealing with virtual events in-between), while the other only with `bind()`?

Comment: @Babber: I don't understand what you're asking. If a key sequence is bound to a virtual event, you must remove it from the virtual event before overriding it. Or, you can override the binding to the virtual event itself. Tkinter isn't making any special rules, it's all deterministic.

Comment: In other words: this worked in the above example: `self.t1.bind_class('Text', '<Control-b>', self.func)`, however this did not: `self.t1.bind_class('Text', '<Control-B>', self.func)`. This is what I don't get yet. What is the qualitative difference between the two?

Comment: @Babber: it is because `<Control-B>` is the same as `<Control-Shift-Key-B>`, and that is translates to `<<SelectPrevChar>>`. `<Control-b>` is not associated with a virtual event.

Comment: "`<Control-b>` is not associated with a virtual event." This is the part that I needed. All clear. Thanks!